# Typescript/React: typescript not recognising props provided via React.cloneElement()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm currently writing a series of unit tests using Jest/Enzyme in a Typescript/React project. In order to provide translations, I am using the `react-intl` library. This library provides documentation on how to write helper functions that wrap Enzyme's shallow/mount methods and inject the appropriate props: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Testing-with-React-Intl#enzyme.

This is all working as expected and my tests are passing, however, Typescript is throwing a type check error as it doesn't realise the props are being injected by the wrapper method.

Example below:

**Component:**

```
interface IWrapperProps {
    intl: InjectedIntl;
}

interface IWrapperQuery {
    data?: ISearchTerm;
    loading: boolean;
    error?: Error;
}

const SearchWrapper: SFC<IWrapperProps> = props => {
    return (
        ...
    );
};
```

**Test:**

```
it('renders correctly', async () => {
    const wrapper = mountWithHelpers(<SearchWrapper />, { mocks });
    await wait(50);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**Helper Method:**

```
// Int Provider
const intlProvider = new IntlProvider({ locale: 'en-gb', messages });
const { intl } = intlProvider.getChildContext();

function nodeWithIntlProp(node: any) {
    return React.cloneElement(node, { intl });
}

// Mount render
export function mountWithHelpers(node: any, { context = {}, childContextTypes = {}, mocks = [], store = null, ...additionalOptions } = {}) {
    const reduxStore = store || createStore(() => {});
    return mount(
        <Provider store={reduxStore}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename>
                    {nodeWithIntlProp(node)}
                </MockedProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>,
        {
            context: Object.assign({}, context, { intl }),
            childContextTypes: Object.assign({}, { intl: intlShape }, childContextTypes),
            ...additionalOptions
        }
    );
}
```

The error typescript is throwing is: `Property 'intl' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IWrapperProps'.` I am certain that the prop is being injected as you can see the appropriate prop in the Jest snapshot files. It is simply a matter of Typescript not recognising that the `intl` prop is provided by the wrapper.

Any advice would be much appreciated.